# Java Components Inherit LnF

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jcomponent

I've made a JComponent child from scratch and made basic- and metal-based look and feels for it.  Even if I'm using the metal theme for the entire application, I still have to call setUI on the object to make it metal.  Is there any way for it to use the current LnF if it's available and default to basic?

Comment: don't mixing two L&Fs in one container, is possible but road to troubles, anyway for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilble, just about a.m. issze

Comment: I'm not trying to mix them, I want the instances of the component I made to pick the right L&F automatically.  My application is metal, by default, but if I simply add the component, it chooses the basic L&F.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `updateUI()` in your `JComponent` and install any custom settings you want:

```
@Override
public void updateUI() {
    super.updateUI();
    // customize here
}
```

Comment: It extends `JComponent` directly, so `super.updateUI()` does nothing.  I think because I'm doing all the drawing myself, I might just have to resign to using something like if (current theme is this) use this UI, etc.

Comment: You're right about `super`; `JComponent#updateUI() is empty, too.